# How to access values inside nested JSON objects in swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift, rest

My goal is to fetch closest restaurants to my location and display those restaurants to the user in table view. I need to decode this API response and access some of its value pairs("name", "url" and "aggregate_rating" to be exact). But when I try to serialize JSON response and print it on terminal this is what I get(I know its quite long)

```
        {
        restaurant =         {
            R =             {
                "has_menu_status" =                 {
                    delivery = "-1";
                    takeaway = "-1";
                };
                "res_id" = 16694062;
            };
            apikey = e06745d59aa6170842e9760500129d63;
            "average_cost_for_two" = 50;
            "book_again_url" = "";
            "book_form_web_view_url" = "";
            cuisines = Turkish;
            currency = TL;
            deeplink = "zomato://restaurant/16694062";
            "events_url" = "https://www.zomato.com/izmir/sen-mutfak-altievler/events#tabtop?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1";
            "featured_image" = "";
            "has_online_delivery" = 0;
            "has_table_booking" = 0;
            id = 16694062;
            "include_bogo_offers" = 1;
            "is_book_form_web_view" = 0;
            "is_delivering_now" = 0;
            "is_table_reservation_supported" = 0;
            "is_zomato_book_res" = 0;
            location =             {
                address = "MOTOPORNE \U00c7IKMAZI SEHITLIK, NARLIDERE \nIZMIR, Altievler, Izmir";
                city = Izmir;
                "city_id" = 376;
                "country_id" = 208;
                latitude = "38.3997300000";
                locality = Altievler;
                "locality_verbose" = "Altievler, Izmir";
                longitude = "27.0005000000";
                zipcode = "";
            };
            "menu_url" = "https://www.zomato.com/izmir/sen-mutfak-altievler/menu?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1&openSwipeBox=menu&showMinimal=1#tabtop";
            "mezzo_provider" = OTHER;
            name = "Sen Mutfak";
            offers =             (
            );
            "opentable_support" = 0;
            "photos_url" = "https://www.zomato.com/izmir/sen-mutfak-altievler/photos?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1#tabtop";
            "price_range" = 2;
            "switch_to_order_menu" = 0;
            thumb = "";
            url = "https://www.zomato.com/izmir/sen-mutfak-altievler?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1";
            "user_rating" =             {
                "aggregate_rating" = "3.4";
                "rating_color" = CDD614;
                "rating_obj" =                 {
                    "bg_color" =                     {
                        tint = 500;
                        type = lime;
                    };
                    title =                     {
                        text = "3.4";
                    };
                };
                "rating_text" = Average;
                votes = 7;
            };
        };
    },
        {
        restaurant =         {
            R =             {
                "has_menu_status" =                 {
                    delivery = "-1";
                    takeaway = "-1";
                };
                "res_id" = 16689453;
            };
            apikey = e06745d59aa6170842e9760500129d63;
            "average_cost_for_two" = 100;
            "book_again_url" = "";
            "book_form_web_view_url" = "";
            cuisines = "Fresh Fish, Seafood";
            currency = TL;
            deeplink = "zomato://restaurant/16689453";
            "events_url" = "https://www.zomato.com/izmir/bizim-gazino-narlidere/events#tabtop?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1";
            "featured_image" = "";
            "has_online_delivery" = 0;
            "has_table_booking" = 0;
            id = 16689453;
            "include_bogo_offers" = 1;
            "is_book_form_web_view" = 0;
            "is_delivering_now" = 0;
            "is_table_reservation_supported" = 0;
            "is_zomato_book_res" = 0;
            location =             {
                address = "Kumsal Sok. 110, Narlidere/Izmir";
                city = Izmir;
                "city_id" = 376;
                "country_id" = 208;
                latitude = "38.3995000000";
                locality = Narlidere;
                "locality_verbose" = "Narlidere, Izmir";
                longitude = "26.9865000000";
                zipcode = "";
            };
            "menu_url" = "https://www.zomato.com/izmir/bizim-gazino-narlidere/menu?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1&openSwipeBox=menu&showMinimal=1#tabtop";
            "mezzo_provider" = OTHER;
            name = "Bizim Gazino";
            offers =             (
            );
            "opentable_support" = 0;
            "photos_url" = "https://www.zomato.com/izmir/bizim-gazino-narlidere/photos?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1#tabtop";
            "price_range" = 3;
            "switch_to_order_menu" = 0;
            thumb = "";
            url = "https://www.zomato.com/izmir/bizim-gazino-narlidere?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1";
            "user_rating" =             {
                "aggregate_rating" = "3.5";
                "rating_color" = 9ACD32;
                "rating_obj" =                 {
                    "bg_color" =                     {
                        tint = 500;
                        type = lime;
                    };
                    title =                     {
                        text = "3.5";
                    };
                };
                "rating_text" = Good;
                votes = 12;
            };
        };
    },
        {
        restaurant =         {
            R =             {
                "has_menu_status" =                 {
                    delivery = "-1";
                    takeaway = "-1";
                };
                "res_id" = 16694494;
            };
            apikey = e06745d59aa6170842e9760500129d63;
            "average_cost_for_two" = 50;
            "book_again_url" = "";
            "book_form_web_view_url" = "";
            cuisines = Turkish;
            currency = TL;
            deeplink = "zomato://restaurant/16694494";
            "events_url" = "https://www.zomato.com/izmir/\U00e7amalti-keyfi-altievler/events#tabtop?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1";
            "featured_image" = "";
            "has_online_delivery" = 0;
            "has_table_booking" = 0;
            id = 16694494;
            "include_bogo_offers" = 1;
            "is_book_form_web_view" = 0;
            "is_delivering_now" = 0;
            "is_table_reservation_supported" = 0;
            "is_zomato_book_res" = 0;
            location =             {
                address = "Narlidere Tansas Yolu \U00dczeri IZMIR, Altievler, Izmir";
                city = Izmir;
                "city_id" = 376;
                "country_id" = 208;
                latitude = "38.3985300000";
                locality = Altievler;
                "locality_verbose" = "Altievler, Izmir";
                longitude = "27.0020200000";
                zipcode = "";
            };
            "menu_url" = "https://www.zomato.com/izmir/\U00e7amalti-keyfi-altievler/menu?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1&openSwipeBox=menu&showMinimal=1#tabtop";
            "mezzo_provider" = OTHER;
            name = "\U00c7amalti Keyfi";
            offers =             (
            );
            "opentable_support" = 0;
            "photos_url" = "https://www.zomato.com/izmir/\U00e7amalti-keyfi-altievler/photos?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1#tabtop";
            "price_range" = 2;
            "switch_to_order_menu" = 0;
            thumb = "";
            url = "https://www.zomato.com/izmir/\U00e7amalti-keyfi-altievler?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1";
            "user_rating" =             {
                "aggregate_rating" = 0;
                "rating_color" = CBCBCB;
                "rating_obj" =                 {
                    "bg_color" =                     {
                        tint = 400;
                        type = grey;
                    };
                    title =                     {
                        text = "-";
                    };
                };
                "rating_text" = "Not rated";
                votes = 1;
            };
        };
    },
        {
        restaurant =         {
            R =             {
                "has_menu_status" =                 {
                    delivery = "-1";
                    takeaway = "-1";
                };
                "res_id" = 16696143;
            };
            apikey = e06745d59aa6170842e9760500129d63;
            "average_cost_for_two" = 25;
            "book_again_url" = "";
            "book_form_web_view_url" = "";
            cuisines = Patisserie;
            currency = TL;
            deeplink = "zomato://restaurant/16696143";
            "events_url" = "https://www.zomato.com/izmir/nil-pastanesi-narlidere/events#tabtop?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1";
            "featured_image" = "";
            "has_online_delivery" = 0;
            "has_table_booking" = 0;
            id = 16696143;
            "include_bogo_offers" = 1;
            "is_book_form_web_view" = 0;
            "is_delivering_now" = 0;
            "is_table_reservation_supported" = 0;
            "is_zomato_book_res" = 0;
            location =             {
                address = "Mithatpasa Cad. No: 325/A, Narlidere / Izmir, Narlidere, Izmir";
                city = Izmir;
                "city_id" = 376;
                "country_id" = 208;
                latitude = "38.3944000000";
                locality = Narlidere;
                "locality_verbose" = "Narlidere, Izmir";
                longitude = "27.0050000000";
                zipcode = "";
            };
            "menu_url" = "https://www.zomato.com/izmir/nil-pastanesi-narlidere/menu?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1&openSwipeBox=menu&showMinimal=1#tabtop";
            "mezzo_provider" = OTHER;
            name = "Nil Pastanesi";
            offers =             (
            );
            "opentable_support" = 0;
            "photos_url" = "https://www.zomato.com/izmir/nil-pastanesi-narlidere/photos?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1#tabtop";
            "price_range" = 1;
            "switch_to_order_menu" = 0;
            thumb = "";
            url = "https://www.zomato.com/izmir/nil-pastanesi-narlidere?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1";
            "user_rating" =             {
                "aggregate_rating" = 0;
                "rating_color" = CBCBCB;
                "rating_obj" =                 {
                    "bg_color" =                     {
                        tint = 400;
                        type = grey;
                    };
                    title =                     {
                        text = "-";
                    };
                };
                "rating_text" = "Not rated";
                votes = 3;
            };
        };
    },
        {
        restaurant =         {
            R =             {
                "has_menu_status" =                 {
                    delivery = "-1";
                    takeaway = "-1";
                };
                "res_id" = 16696674;
            };
            apikey = e06745d59aa6170842e9760500129d63;
            "average_cost_for_two" = 40;
            "book_again_url" = "";
            "book_form_web_view_url" = "";
            cuisines = Izgara;
            currency = TL;
            deeplink = "zomato://restaurant/16696674";
            "events_url" = "https://www.zomato.com/izmir/kanat\U00e7i-h\U00fcso-narlidere/events#tabtop?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1";
            "featured_image" = "";
            "has_online_delivery" = 0;
            "has_table_booking" = 0;
            id = 16696674;
            "include_bogo_offers" = 1;
            "is_book_form_web_view" = 0;
            "is_delivering_now" = 0;
            "is_table_reservation_supported" = 0;
            "is_zomato_book_res" = 0;
            location =             {
                address = "\U00c7ESME OTOBAN ALTI NO:2 TANSAS SERVIS YOLU \U00dcZERI\nBal\U00e7ova\nIZMIR, Narlidere, Izmir";
                city = Izmir;
                "city_id" = 376;
                "country_id" = 208;
                latitude = "38.3932000000";
                locality = Narlidere;
                "locality_verbose" = "Narlidere, Izmir";
                longitude = "26.9890000000";
                zipcode = "";
            };
            "menu_url" = "https://www.zomato.com/izmir/kanat\U00e7i-h\U00fcso-narlidere/menu?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1&openSwipeBox=menu&showMinimal=1#tabtop";
            "mezzo_provider" = OTHER;
            name = "Kanat\U00e7i H\U00fcso";
            offers =             (
            );
            "opentable_support" = 0;
            "photos_url" = "https://www.zomato.com/izmir/kanat\U00e7i-h\U00fcso-narlidere/photos?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1#tabtop";
            "price_range" = 2;
            "switch_to_order_menu" = 0;
            thumb = "";
            url = "https://www.zomato.com/izmir/kanat\U00e7i-h\U00fcso-narlidere?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1";
            "user_rating" =             {
                "aggregate_rating" = 0;
                "rating_color" = CBCBCB;
                "rating_obj" =                 {
                    "bg_color" =                     {
                        tint = 400;
                        type = grey;
                    };
                    title =                     {
                        text = "-";
                    };
                };
                "rating_text" = "Not rated";
                votes = 3;
            };
        };
    },
        {
        restaurant =         {
            R =             {
                "has_menu_status" =                 {
                    delivery = "-1";
                    takeaway = "-1";
                };
                "res_id" = 16696286;
            };
            apikey = e06745d59aa6170842e9760500129d63;
            "average_cost_for_two" = 40;
            "book_again_url" = "";
            "book_form_web_view_url" = "";
            cuisines = Cafe;
            currency = TL;
            deeplink = "zomato://restaurant/16696286";
            "events_url" = "https://www.zomato.com/izmir/tar\U00e7in-altievler/events#tabtop?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1";
            "featured_image" = "";
            "has_online_delivery" = 0;
            "has_table_booking" = 0;
            id = 16696286;
            "include_bogo_offers" = 1;
            "is_book_form_web_view" = 0;
            "is_delivering_now" = 0;
            "is_table_reservation_supported" = 0;
            "is_zomato_book_res" = 0;
            location =             {
                address = "Yildirim Kemal Cad., Altievler Mah., No:16 Sahilevleri / Izmir, Altievler, Izmir";
                city = Izmir;
                "city_id" = 376;
                "country_id" = 208;
                latitude = "38.3976000000";
                locality = Altievler;
                "locality_verbose" = "Altievler, Izmir";
                longitude = "26.9975000000";
                zipcode = "";
            };
            "menu_url" = "https://www.zomato.com/izmir/tar\U00e7in-altievler/menu?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1&openSwipeBox=menu&showMinimal=1#tabtop";
            "mezzo_provider" = OTHER;
            name = "Tar\U00e7in";
            offers =             (
            );
            "opentable_support" = 0;
            "photos_url" = "https://www.zomato.com/izmir/tar\U00e7in-altievler/photos?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1#tabtop";
            "price_range" = 2;
            "switch_to_order_menu" = 0;
            thumb = "";
            url = "https://www.zomato.com/izmir/tar\U00e7in-altievler?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1";
            "user_rating" =             {
                "aggregate_rating" = 0;
                "rating_color" = CBCBCB;
                "rating_obj" =                 {
                    "bg_color" =                     {
                        tint = 400;
                        type = grey;
                    };
                    title =                     {
                        text = "-";
                    };
                };
                "rating_text" = "Not rated";
                votes = 1;
            };
        };
    },
        {
        restaurant =         {
            R =             {
                "has_menu_status" =                 {
                    delivery = "-1";
                    takeaway = "-1";
                };
                "res_id" = 16691486;
            };
            apikey = e06745d59aa6170842e9760500129d63;
            "average_cost_for_two" = 70;
            "book_again_url" = "";
            "book_form_web_view_url" = "";
            cuisines = "Restaurant Cafe";
            currency = TL;
            deeplink = "zomato://restaurant/16691486";
            "events_url" = "https://www.zomato.com/izmir/mavi-yesil-restaurant-narlidere/events#tabtop?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1";
            "featured_image" = "";
            "has_online_delivery" = 0;
            "has_table_booking" = 0;
            id = 16691486;
            "include_bogo_offers" = 1;
            "is_book_form_web_view" = 0;
            "is_delivering_now" = 0;
            "is_table_reservation_supported" = 0;
            "is_zomato_book_res" = 0;
            location =             {
                address = "Mithatpasa Cad. No:465 \U00c7esme Otoban Girisi Karsisi, Narlidere, Izmir";
                city = Izmir;
                "city_id" = 376;
                "country_id" = 208;
                latitude = "38.3956092539";
                locality = Narlidere;
                "locality_verbose" = "Narlidere, Izmir";
                longitude = "26.9942235947";
                zipcode = "";
            };
            "menu_url" = "https://www.zomato.com/izmir/mavi-yesil-restaurant-narlidere/menu?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1&openSwipeBox=menu&showMinimal=1#tabtop";
            "mezzo_provider" = OTHER;
            name = "Mavi Yesil Restaurant";
            offers =             (
            );
            "opentable_support" = 0;
            "photos_url" = "https://www.zomato.com/izmir/mavi-yesil-restaurant-narlidere/photos?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1#tabtop";
            "price_range" = 3;
            "switch_to_order_menu" = 0;
            thumb = "";
            url = "https://www.zomato.com/izmir/mavi-yesil-restaurant-narlidere?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1";
            "user_rating" =             {
                "aggregate_rating" = 0;
                "rating_color" = CBCBCB;
                "rating_obj" =                 {
                    "bg_color" =                     {
                        tint = 400;
                        type = grey;
                    };
                    title =                     {
                        text = "-";
                    };
                };
                "rating_text" = "Not rated";
                votes = 3;
            };
        };
    },
        {
        restaurant =         {
            R =             {
                "has_menu_status" =                 {
                    delivery = "-1";
                    takeaway = "-1";
                };
                "res_id" = 16696730;
            };
            apikey = e06745d59aa6170842e9760500129d63;
            "average_cost_for_two" = 50;
            "book_again_url" = "";
            "book_form_web_view_url" = "";
            cuisines = Izgara;
            currency = TL;
            deeplink = "zomato://restaurant/16696730";
            "events_url" = "https://www.zomato.com/izmir/mangal-borsasi-altievler/events#tabtop?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1";
            "featured_image" = "";
            "has_online_delivery" = 0;
            "has_table_booking" = 0;
            id = 16696730;
            "include_bogo_offers" = 1;
            "is_book_form_web_view" = 0;
            "is_delivering_now" = 0;
            "is_table_reservation_supported" = 0;
            "is_zomato_book_res" = 0;
            location =             {
                address = "Narlidere Sehitlik Karsisi, Altievler, Izmir";
                city = Izmir;
                "city_id" = 376;
                "country_id" = 208;
                latitude = "38.3960000000";
                locality = Altievler;
                "locality_verbose" = "Altievler, Izmir";
                longitude = "26.9978000000";
                zipcode = "";
            };
            "menu_url" = "https://www.zomato.com/izmir/mangal-borsasi-altievler/menu?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1&openSwipeBox=menu&showMinimal=1#tabtop";
            "mezzo_provider" = OTHER;
            name = "Mangal Borsasi";
            offers =             (
            );
            "opentable_support" = 0;
            "photos_url" = "https://www.zomato.com/izmir/mangal-borsasi-altievler/photos?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1#tabtop";
            "price_range" = 2;
            "switch_to_order_menu" = 0;
            thumb = "";
            url = "https://www.zomato.com/izmir/mangal-borsasi-altievler?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1";
            "user_rating" =             {
                "aggregate_rating" = 0;
                "rating_color" = CBCBCB;
                "rating_obj" =                 {
                    "bg_color" =                     {
                        tint = 400;
                        type = grey;
                    };
                    title =                     {
                        text = "-";
                    };
                };
                "rating_text" = "Not rated";
                votes = 2;
            };
        };
    },
        {
        restaurant =         {
            R =             {
                "has_menu_status" =                 {
                    delivery = "-1";
                    takeaway = "-1";
                };
                "res_id" = 16695847;
            };
            apikey = e06745d59aa6170842e9760500129d63;
            "average_cost_for_two" = 40;
            "book_again_url" = "";
            "book_form_web_view_url" = "";
            cuisines = "Turkish Pizza";
            currency = TL;
            deeplink = "zomato://restaurant/16695847";
            "events_url" = "https://www.zomato.com/izmir/annem-pide-narlidere/events#tabtop?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1";
            "featured_image" = "";
            "has_online_delivery" = 0;
            "has_table_booking" = 0;
            id = 16695847;
            "include_bogo_offers" = 1;
            "is_book_form_web_view" = 0;
            "is_delivering_now" = 0;
            "is_table_reservation_supported" = 0;
            "is_zomato_book_res" = 0;
            location =             {
                address = "MITHAT PASA CAD. NO:349, Narlidere, Izmir";
                city = Izmir;
                "city_id" = 376;
                "country_id" = 208;
                latitude = "38.3945000000";
                locality = Narlidere;
                "locality_verbose" = "Narlidere, Izmir";
                longitude = "27.0044000000";
                zipcode = "";
            };
            "menu_url" = "https://www.zomato.com/izmir/annem-pide-narlidere/menu?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1&openSwipeBox=menu&showMinimal=1#tabtop";
            "mezzo_provider" = OTHER;
            name = "Annem Pide";
            offers =             (
            );
            "opentable_support" = 0;
            "photos_url" = "https://www.zomato.com/izmir/annem-pide-narlidere/photos?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1#tabtop";
            "price_range" = 2;
            "switch_to_order_menu" = 0;
            thumb = "";
            url = "https://www.zomato.com/izmir/annem-pide-narlidere?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1";
            "user_rating" =             {
                "aggregate_rating" = 0;
                "rating_color" = CBCBCB;
                "rating_obj" =                 {
                    "bg_color" =                     {
                        tint = 400;
                        type = grey;
                    };
                    title =                     {
                        text = "-";
                    };
                };
                "rating_text" = "Not rated";
                votes = 2;
            };
        };
    }
)
```

This is my custom struct

```
import Foundation

struct User_rating: Codable {
    var aggregate_rating: String
}

struct Restaurant: Codable {
    var name: String
    var url: String
    var thumb: String
    var user_rating: User_rating
    var photos_url: String
}
```

This is where I serialize JSON response:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import CoreLocation

class RestaurantTableViewController: UITableViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    let apiKey: String = "e06745d59aa6170842e9760500129d63"
    let cellIdentifier: String = "restaurantCell"
    var restaurants = [Restaurant]()
    var restaurantImages: [URL] = []
    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    // MARK: Lifecycle methods

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let urlString = """
        https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/geocode?lat=\(locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude)&lon=\(locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude)
        """
        let url = URL(string: urlString)

        if url != nil {
            var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
            request.httpMethod = "GET"
            request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
            request.addValue(apiKey, forHTTPHeaderField: "user-key")

            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
                guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
                let httpResponse = response as! HTTPURLResponse

                if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
                    do {
                        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as! [String:Any]
                        print(json) // Prints the response given above
                    } catch _ {

                    }
                }
            }.resume()
        }
    }
}
```

I have followed several SO answers and other guides. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you are using `Codable` then you don't want JSONSerialization, you should use `JSONDecoder`

Comment: And add a `print(error)` in your `catch`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Swift 5**

You need to replace:

```
    do {
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as! [String:Any]
        print(json) // Prints the response given above
    } catch _ {

    }
```

with

```swift
    struct RestaurantWrapper {
        let restaurant: Restaurant
    }
    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let list: [RestaurantWrapper] = try decoder.decode([RestaurantWrapper].self, from: data)
    } catch let error {
        print("ERROR: \(error)") //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! never halt errors
    }
```

Comment: I just tried to do it the way you did but I encountered "The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format." error. And I get the following error "typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))".Any ideas why?

Comment: @ErdalGüzel you need to follow the format exactly in your models. Use `RestaurantWrapper` (I updated the answer)

Comment: This error("typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))") still persists. Any ideas why?

Comment: @ErdalGüzel I already answered you - update the models to follow your response. Start with empty top model object, then add fields and try each time if it parses correctly. The error you show is obvious - "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead." - one of the fields is array, but in response it's dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Try json decoder

```swift
guard let serverResponse = response, let data = response.data?.string(encoding: .utf8) else { return }

do {
let model:yourCustomModel = try decoder.decode(yourCustomModel.self, from: data)
} catch {
print ("Error while decoding json : \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```